# Choosing file and drag drop file using angular

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui

Here I’m able to select file and show it in kendo grid upon selection. I want to include drag and drop and update dragged file in the grid.

Here’s my html code:

```
‹kendo-grid [data]="myFiles".    (remove)="removeHandler ($event)"
‹ng-template                   kendoGridToolbarTemplate      position="bottom" )

‹input type="file"               [disabled]="readonlyMode Il      readonlyVersion" (change)-   "uploadFile($event)" title="upload"    value-"Upload"/ >
 </ng-template›

 ‹kendo-grid-command-column     title="Remove" [width]="220"
 ‹ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate     field-"id" let-value>

 ‹button kendoGridRemoveCommand›<span    class="k-icon k-i-close k-icon-32"   (click)-"showconfirmpopup-true" ›</span>             </button>
 ‹kendo-   dialog*ngIf="showconfirmpopup==true">
   <div>Are you sure you want to remove this attachment?k/divf
    ‹div>
      «span›‹button kendoButton (click)-  "delete(value.id)" (click) -"showconfirmpopup-false"›Okay</button>          </span>
      «5pan>‹button kendoButton (click)-   "showconfirmpopup=false" ›Cancel</button>  </span>
     </div>
 </kendo-dialog›
</ng-template›
</kendo-grid-command-column>
«kendo-grid-column field-"name"   title-"Name"
```

> ```
> «/kendo-grid-column>
> ```

```
‹kendo-grid-command-column title-"Download" field-"file" [width]="220'
‹ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate                     ‹kendo-grid [data]="myFiles"
```

I’m attaching snapshot of ui here[ui look when I choose a file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERVnD.jpg)